# doubt in for loop

Tags: java

i have the following code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  int x=0;
  int y=0;
  for(int z=0;z<5;z++)
    if((++x>2)||(++y>2))
      x++;

  System.out.println(x+" "+y);

}
```

For this the output is 8 2

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  int x=0;
  int y=0;
  for(int z=0;z<5;z++){
    if((++x>2)||(++y>2))
      x++;

    System.out.println(x+" "+y);
  } 
}
```

i can understand the second code that it prints everytime till the loop completes.
For the first code 
when x becomes 3 in the if loop value will be incremented to 4 and after that what well happen will it go to sop or to for loop to complete the loop?

Comment: **Wow** does that first code snippet need braces. This question is why *always* using braces is a Good Thing(tm).

Comment: What is the question here? If you want to know what the code does, just run it (possibly in a debugger). Or is it that you don't understand why it does what it does? Then please ask a more specific question.

Comment: a) the second exampke has an extra } (or a missing {), so it's not clear what the difference between the two functions is supposed to be b) you loop variable is z. What you do do x won't affect the loop at all so it's not clear what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i editet you entry because you missed to mak your code as such... after reading the question, i think you should see the answer yourself if you look at how it's indented.

for the future: use curly braces *every time*, not just if there is more than one line in the block, otherwise you will only get confused.

Answer (score 1):

The for loop is controlled by the value of z, the value of x has no bearing on when the loop stops.